# What I am misunderstanding with code that prints a pyramid?

Tags: java, character

My code is supposed to make a pryamid. The example below, however, is supposed to have another `A` character at the end, like the second example.

```
ABCDDCBA
 ABCCBA
  ABBA
   AA

ABCDDCBA
 ABCCBA
  ABBA
   AA
   A
```

This is my code. It starts with `ABCDDCBA`, and removes the characters in the middle each time. So `ABCDDCBA` would be `ABCCBA` as the Ds get removed. However, when there are two characters (always the same) the code is supposed to remove one, but it doesn't.

```
public static void pyramid(int n) 
{ 
    int i, j, num, gap; 

    // outer loop to handle number 
    // of rows n in this case 
    for (i = n; i >= 0; i--) { 

        // inner loop to create right triangle 
        // gaps on left side of pyramid 
        for (gap = n - 1; gap >= i; gap--) { 
            System.out.print(" "); 
            System.out.print(" "); 
        } 

        // initializing value corresponding to ASCII value of 'A'  
        num = 'A'; 

        // loop to print characters on 
        // left side of pyramid 
        for (j = 1; j <= i; j++) { 
            System.out.print((char)num++ + " "); 
        } 

        // loop to print characters on 
        // right side of pyramid 
        for (j = i - 0; j >= 1; j--) { 
            System.out.print((char)--num + " "); 
        } 

        System.out.println(""); 
    }
}
public static void main(String[] args) 
{ 
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = sc.nextInt(); 
    pyramid(n); 

}
```

Please help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code:

```
for (j = i - 0; j >= 1; j--) {
```

should be

```
for (j = i - 1; j >= 1; j--) {
```